# What should i do to display line no in text editor ,which we have design using Gtk in c?

Tags: gtk

I am doing text editor.I wanted to use function that will display line no of text editor.I got the function to get line number,but i wanted to show that no on window and user should not be allowed to change that no.I think i should do separate panel on text editor to display line no>

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use GtkSourceView instead of a TextView (e.g. the widget used by gedit among others), there are specific methods ready to use such as:

```
gtk_source_view_set_show_line_numbers
```

https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/GtkSourceView.html#gtk-source-view-set-show-line-numbers